# Problem with grid labels in grid composer

Tags: print-composer, grids-graticules

I am having some trouble with the print composer. First I set a fixed scale the proper scale for my map. Second, I set the width and height. Third I set the fixed X and Y minimum for my map.

For instance, I have a map that I want at a 1: 5,000 scale. Width is 240mm which would display 1,200m. Height is 160mm which would display 800m. X minimum is 481,000 and Y minimum is 2,136,000.

When I add a grid, I expected to see my minimum X and Y in the lower right corner and on the Top right corner. Nevertheless, the labels do not appear. I can only see labels for 482,200 in the Lower and Top corners, no label for my Y minimum in the lower left corner but the 2,136,800 at the top right corner. 
I wonder if I am missing a step or some option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that implies two steps:

First instead the height and and width is associated with the specific limits you want to use, plan ahead to be a little bit "bigger".

Second, define a limit (X and/or Y minimum) that is slightly less than the limit you want to show. For instance, I wanted the 481,000 label and I used as a reference. If I define the X minimum as 480,995, it will show the label. For the north instead of 2,136,000 I used 2,135,995 and that did the trick.

So, I defined an area a little bit bigger and X and Y minimums shorter than the ones I used before...

[image]